# add and remove from and to string in jquery on image press

Tags: jquery, html

I have a situation where I need to add items to a string on the first click and remove them on the second click of the same image.
for example
I have 3 images on the website , having respectively the following names cat , dog and rabbit and a string in jquery called  choice
if cat pressed
choice = cat
if dog is then press
choice = cat , dog
now if cat is pressed again (unpressed)
choice = dog
if rabbit is pressed
choice = dog, rabbit
and so on
how can I do that?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets me give you example

cat,dog ,rabbit has there own id.
on click of Particular Item add that id to array.

```js
var itemArr=[];
function AddMe(id){


//on item click  check :
var index= itemArr.indexOf(id);
//array contains id
if(index<=-1){
//on item click 
itemArr.push(id);
}else{
itemArr.splice(index,1);

}

$("#result").html(itemArr.join(","));
}
```

```css
.red{
color:red;
font-weight:bold;
}

.brown{
color:brown;
font-weight:bold;
}
.black{
color:black;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="cat" class="red" onclick="AddMe(id)">Cat </label>
<label id="dog" class="brown" onclick="AddMe(id)">Dog </label>
<label id="rabbit" class="black" onclick="AddMe(id)">Rabbit </label>
<br/>
<label>Array Item :</label>
<label id="result"></label>
```

same way you can do for other items.

Comment: thank you so much , I used those functions to classes and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Fieldset and Legend for each option, and an event listener for changes. When fired it can loop through the options and populate a string array with the selected options. Then simply loop through the array appending or prefixing a variable with it's contents seperated by a comma.

If you make an attempt at the solution I will fix any issues you come across, if you edit this answer with your attempt.